# Using Google Forms (or Google Apps Scripts) to update existing Google Sheets cell values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So what I'm trying to do is pretty complicated, or seems like it to me as I have 0 coding experience.

I'd like to use a Google Form to collect information from my students about damages or repairs to equipment at a tech school. I want each component or job to have a cash value, so for example, a blown control board would be -$600 for that student's earnings, or a repaired board would be +$600.

I can set the form up to collect the data about which components were damaged or repaired no problem, but I have no idea how (or if I even can,) to script taking the text (Control Board, Capacitor, etc) from the cell (Damaged Parts or Repaired Parts) and using an onSubmit or onUpdate trigger to turn those parts into numerical values and update and existing cell on a separate sheet for that student.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A good question includes some code and an explanation of what you have tried.  You have stated that you have 0 coding experience.  You will need to do some learning on your own.  Stack Overflow is not for general advice, or to recommend a book, tutorial or off-site resource.  A good place to start would be to open the Apps Script code editor, and choose the "Help" menu and then "Getting Started."  The Apps Script code editor can be opened in various ways.  From a spreadsheet choose "Tools" and "Script Editor."

Comment: You may want to join the  [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: All of the forms I've messed with append all of their data as a single line added to the bottom of the sheet that the form is linked to.  You can use the onSubmitForm event to get event.values which is an row array of the submit data.  So it sounds to me like it's a possibility. Sometimes problems like these can seem quite daunting so you should plan to write something like this several times before you get what you really like.  Try not to do everything in one function.  The first time you write the code go through it and try to identify things that can be broken into smaller functions.